# Why Tag synonymizing needs so much rep?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms

Why do you need so much reputation in order to propose Tag synonyms?

Answer (score 4):

Because we want users to realize the usage of tags and how they work before they can propose tags synonymous.

Anyone with some reputation can edit, remove, fix posts with some reviewing associated. It is ok and part of the site that the community is responsible for them.

Tag synonymous on the other hand gets registered in the site and will affect the inner works of the site, you should at least have spent some time understanding how the site works before the site allows you to do so.

Tag synonymous requires votes to pass, I would hate to be reverting synonymous voted by a group of low reputation users or to have the suggestion list filled with noise, even so, the reputation required is not has high as you think and as I wanted.

Another point of the way we work is that even **a user with a low reputation can suggest a tag synonymous: you can do so via a meta post with that proposition.**
We can then further discuss, agree or disagree and move to action if in favor and create the tag synonymous.

Other than that it requires that users with some reputation and that participate on the site agree and vote for them.

Comment: `even a user with a low reputation can suggest a tag synonymous: you can do so via a meta post with that proposition.` Yes but this user does all the hard work but doesn't receive any rep or badges at all.

Comment: I do not know how many times I have said this already, but: _reputation (number) != reputation (actions)_. If you want to suggest a tag synonymous and you have low reputation because you are a new user, asking goes a long way in to learning the site and letting others learn, assist you and teach you if needed. Letting a bunch of low reputation users create tag synonymous is a bad idea. Remember, actions, learning and sharing are better than a badge or reputation. Besides, there are already 100.000 ways of getting reputation on the site :/

Comment: `there are already 100.000 ways of getting reputation on the site` I think you are overreacting with this statement.

Comment: @pl1nk that is not the discussion here I think

Comment: You can still point me to a link/question ?

Comment: hum? what are you looking for more?